# database size constraint in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am working on an app which stores plenty of images in the DB from an online search. When there are 5000x4 images being stored in the DB at one time, the app crashes. 
What I would like to know is, is it that the database is exceeding certain (limited) size or is it that there are too many activities being performed on the DB causing it to crash.

PS : It worked fine in the simulator thou.

Comment: Are you using core data? Are the images stored right away after download? What is the crash reason? What size the images are?

Comment: @BerndRabe : Yes, I am using core dara. THe images are stored right away in the DB. I am unaware of the crash reason as of now. The images are of size 8 KB each.

Answer (score 1):

1) If the total database size will be only a few hundred megs, then you can safely and effectively use a SQL backed Core Data repository for the images.

2) When you start getting close to a gig or more, then you should save the larger (or all) images in files, and use Core Data to keep a reference (file path or URL) to the images. The way to do this is (for ios 5.1 and newer) is create a directory inside the "Application Support" directory (which you may need to create), mark it so that is is not included in iCloud backups, and store the images there. In this manner you can keep around gigs of data (assuming the user doesn't get upset and delete your app).

EDIT: I just read your comment. Assuming a large number of small (8K) images, if the issue is having them all active at one time (that is, you are setting entity attributes all at one time, not over a long time), then you may need to make the entity 'fault' using 'refreshObject:mergeChanges:'. You can read about this in the Core Data Programming Guide along with other tips on reducing memory footprints.

Comment: seems like we are having same thinking @David.

Comment: @David H : thanks for the direction. I shall implement the approach you mentioned and revert on this post.